# Asynchronous database execution using Spring-Boot and Spring-JPA

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring-boot-starter-parent 2.1.7.RELEASE version along with spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and postgresql. My requirement is to pass a List of String containing user first-names to the backend which will compute Asynchronously if the user is present in the database or not and return a map containing the user-name with boolean (true if present, false if not). Please check the service and repository layers below. Any thoughts would be welcome.

**Service**

```
@Async(value="threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public CompletableFuture<Map<String, Boolean>> findIfEmpByFirstNamePresentAsync(List<String> firstNameList) {

        Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

        firstNameList.stream().forEach(firstName -> {
            CompletableFuture<Integer> cfi = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                return employeeRepository.countEmpByFirstName(firstName);
            });
            try {
                map.put(firstName, cfi.get() > 0 ? true : false);
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(map);
    }
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {

        @Query("select count(*) from Employee e where e.firstName like %:firstName%")
        public Integer countEmpByFirstName(String firstName);

}
```

Comment: what is the issue here? Is this code not working?

Comment: Yes the code is working, I just wanted some valuable opinions if this is the right approach to the problem , or are there some optimizations that can be done. FYI, here is the sample caller code :    `List<String> firstNameList = Arrays.asList("Pradosh","Deja","Ravi");
  CompletableFuture<Map<String, Boolean>> completableFutureP = employeeService.findIfEmpByFirstNamePresentAsync(firstNameList);
  Map<String, Boolean> map = completableFutureP.get(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  map.entrySet().stream().forEach(System.out::println);`